# Hook when reading the database

Tags: wordpress

I need a WordPress hook which will able me to change the post content when reading the database for showing content in editor for editing or in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_edit_pre) is what you're looking for.

**Taken from WordPress.org:**

```
function filter_function_name( $content, $post_id ) {
    // Process content here
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'content_edit_pre', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );
```

**Edit:**

Since the **OP** has asked for some clarification on what filter priorities do and when to use them, here's an update.

**What the `$priority` parameter is for as defined by the WordPress Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter):**

> Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a
>   particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier
>   execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the
>   order in which they were added to the action.

It's also important to note when removing a filter, priority is also important:

**Excerpted from [WordPress Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter):**

> Important: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority
>   arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both
>   filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, I have applied the same last night, but it did not work for me. But here you have added the priorities. So my question is how to know what priorities to set at what time to what hook. Please give me some reference, where I would know more about hook priorities.

Comment: It is not working always. I have four blog articles. There I changed some URL in the database. I have written some code which will change some part of the URL and show it in browse or in admin panel for edit, but it is not coming after first occurrence. Can you help in this thing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the information you requested in your first comment. I'm not sure I follow your second comment, though. It sounds like it may be outside the scope of this question and should be in a new thread, but I could be wrong since I don't really know what you're asking.